# Easy way to get IP address from hostname using a Unix shell

Tags: unix, shell, ip, hostname

What is the easiest way to get the IP address from a hostname?

I was thinking about trying a [`ping`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) and parse it from the output. However, that doesn't seem very nice and will probably not work the same way on all systems.

I searched a bit around and found solutions with [`nslookup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup), but that doesn't work for hostnames in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I still wonder a bit why Unix shells are not considered as programming languages...

Comment: Because shell traditionally is seen as scripting, not programming ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with standard system calls. Here's an example in Perl:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Socket;
use Data::Dumper;

my @addresses = gethostbyname('google.com');
my @ips = map { inet_ntoa($_) } @addresses[4 .. $#addresses];
print Dumper(\@ips);
```

produces the output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '74.125.127.104',
          '74.125.127.103',
          '74.125.127.105',
          '74.125.127.106',
          '74.125.127.147',
          '74.125.127.99'
        ];
```

(On the command-line, the same script can be written as: `perl  -MSocket -MData::Dumper -wle'my @addresses = gethostbyname("google.com"); my @ips = map { inet_ntoa($_) } @addresses[4 .. $#addresses]; print Dumper(\@ips)'`)

**You can do this similarly in other languages -- see the man page for the
system calls at `man -s3 gethostbyname` etc.**

Comment: Cool, that works. Esp., `perl -MSocket -MData::Dumper -wle'my @addresses = gethostbyname("www.google.com"); my @ips = map { inet_ntoa($_) } @addresses[4 .. $#addresses]; print $ips[0]'`.

Comment: Very strange that this answer is some program code... :) Looks almost like a Stackoverflow answer. Doesn't really belong on Serverfault. But I'll accept the answer anyway.

Comment: @Albert: well to be fair: 1. the question was posted on SO originally and migrated to SF, and 2. the type of data you're looking for needs to be parsed with *something*; some people consider Perl a better form of shell script :D

Comment: @Ether `sed -e '/some people consider Perl a better form/s/better/worse/'` SCNR

Answer (score 15):

`host <hostname>`

Ex:

```
serv ~ $ host stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 69.59.196.211
```

## Edit

On Linux, (and some OS X variants, at least), you might be able to use [`resolveip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/resolveip), which is part of the MySQL server package:

```
/etc/hosts:
 ...
 127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain foo
 ...

serv ~ $ resolveip foo
IP address of foo is 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Also does not work. (For hosts in `/etc/hosts`.) Try `host localhost`.

Comment: `serv ~ $ host localhost \n localhost has address 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Hm, well, not here. I'm curious why that works for you. Or why it does not for me.

Comment: See my edit - you might try `resolveip`.

Comment: Hm, `resolveip` is not installed by default on my Debian.

Comment: it works on mine too. maybe it's because both me and Amber are on OSX? (at least, I think he's on OSX :D)

Comment: @klez I'm a he now?
@Albert Looks like it's actually part of the MySQL server package.

Comment: Hehe, how does that belong to MySQL? :) Well...

Comment: It's mostly that MySQL distributes it so that it can use it.

Comment: @Amber: pardon, your profile didn't give much info, but I had a suspect XD

Answer (score 12):

This ancient post seem to have many creative solutions.

If I need to make sure also `/etc/hosts` gets accessed, I tend to use

`getent hosts somehost.com`

This works, at least if `/etc/nsswitch.conf' has been configured to use files (as it usually is).

Comment: Nice, and works for IPv6, too.

Comment: And doesn't need installing syslinux!

Comment: Interesting that for some IPs it returns nothing while `ahosts` does return multi-line info.

Answer (score 7):

For IPv4 there is a standard program which works out of the box using the resolver including /etc/hosts:

```
host="localhost"
ip="`gethostip -d "$host"`"
```

It is part of Debian, install it with:

```
apt-get install syslinux
```

For other protocols than IPv4 (like IPv6) I currently don't know a similar tool. **Update:**  Because of this I just wrote a small tool which is capable to resolve IPv6, too:

https://github.com/hilbix/misc/blob/master/src/ipof.c

It is thought for a quick and dirty shell use like `gethostip` but allows IPv6, too:

```
ip="`ipof -6 -- heise.de`"
```

It also can be used interactively, for example:

```
ipof -a -d -x -v -h -
```

HTH

Comment: Came here to give this answer, up-voted you instead.

Answer (score 6):

Why not `dig +short hostname` ?

(query DNS)

Comment: It does not take `/etc/hosts` into account.

Comment: DNS is supposed to be a definitive source for Name Resolution, and if you use the host file to override, that's fine. But that's an override, not definitive...

Comment: I know, but the original question wanted /etc/hosts :)

Comment: sure enough; my reading comprehension fail...

Answer (score 3):

Well, my current solution:

```
ping -c1 -n www.google.com | head -n1 | sed "s/.*(\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)).*/\1/g"
```

Comment: this doesn't give only the IP: PING www.l.google.com (72.14.234.104): 56 data bytes

Comment: Yea, seems that `sed` behaves slightly different on each system. :) How annoying. I changed it a bit, I think it should work everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

On some Unices, the following will work:

```
arp <hostname>
```

For example on Mac OS X, I get this:

```
arp My-iMac.local
My-iMac.local (192.168.1.2) -- no entry
```

Comment: Well, it finds the entry but it only lists its MAC, not its IP. :)

Comment: Ah, `arp -n hostname` shows the IP.

Comment: Only, this way doesn't work for servers outside the network. :P

Answer (score 0):

Using `ping` is not that bad since you generally do not have any strong dependencies.

Here is the function I used on Linux systems :

```
getip () { ping -c 1 -t 1 $1 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr -d '()' ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a Python one-liner. Should work on all OS:

```
python -c "import sys, socket; print (socket.gethostbyname('<hostname>'))"
```

This can be embedded easily in a shell script:

```
function gethostip() {
    python -c "import sys, socket; print (socket.gethostbyname('$1'))"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24|grep SEARCHED_HOSTNAME|sed -n 's/.*[(]\([0-9\.]*\)[)].*/\1/p'
```

- Nmap gets from your subnet (192.168.1.0 or whatever) the adresses
- with grep get only the line of the hostname you are looking for
- With sed get only the ip address inside the parentheses

Comment: A bit more info on the various switches and why used would add to your answer

Comment: There are at least four different reasons why this answer is not going to work. You make assumptions about the range of IP addresses within which the answer will be found. It is inefficient due to producing a lot more network traffic than needed. It only works for IP addresses which responds to probes. It assumes reverse DNS contains the exact same mappings as forward DNS.